# How do I exclude a particular woocommerce product category from the list of displayed categores

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce shortcode [product_categories hide_empty=0] for woocommerce shortcode docs, to display all my product categories in my shop page name mysitename/sabiresearchshop. However, I want to exclude just a category called Premium Membership from this list of displayed product categories How can I do it.

I have tried the code below to no avail:

```
function sabi_customize_product_shortcode( $args, $atts ) {
if ( is_page (119) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'premium-membership' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
   );
}

return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'sabi_customize_product_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Have you tried it with "premium-membership" in capital letters? Or might the term for that category be different?
Also, have you seen and tried [this](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-category-product-categories-shortcode/)?

Comment: This seems like a bug for this particular Shortcode… You should report it on Woocommerce support threads.